# How to run Xcode 6.2 simulator?

Tags: xcode

At the top next to the play/run button, I only have an option for "iOS Device".  The simulator is not an option.  How do I run projects in the simulator?

Comment: Did you downloaded Simulators in Xcode "Preferences -> Downloads"?

Comment: Yes - I have iOS 8.1 simulator.  Although my target is 8.2.  Not sure if it makes any difference.  It doesn't show there is anything else to download.

Comment: Check your minimum deployment target. If it is 8.2 and and your don't have 8.2 simulator installed, simulator won't show up.

Comment: How do I get the 8.2 simulator?  Shouldn't that come with Xcode?

Comment: Yes, it is installed with Xcode. Also what is your "iOS Deployment Target" under target "Build Settings".

Comment: Deployment Target = 8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually start the simulator from the task bar. I think its under File -> Developer Tools -> iOS Simulator.

Also make sure your deployment target is set to the simulator's firmware.

If still you can't use the simulator you can tap on `iOS Device` and then add scheme. There you will be able to add simulators, even though this should have been there by default.

Comment: Deployment target is iOS 8.2 and for what ever reason, the simulator is now running.  No idea what changed.

Comment: what did you do that fixed it?